# Mod_rewrite Mask URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I need to rewrite https://mydomain1.com/chanagepassword to https://mydomain2.com/ssp

then hide the url mydomain2.com/cp in browser and show https://mydomain1.com/chanagepassword.

I got the first part working with the rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /changepassword https://mydomain2.com/ssp/ [R=301,L]
```

However it shows https://mydomain2.com/ssp url on browser. How can I mask this and show https://mydomain1.com/chanagepassword

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
SSLProxyCheckExpire on
ProxyPass /changepassword https://mydomain2.com/ssp
ProxyPassReverse /changepassword https://mydomain2.com/ssp
```

"Please support" is a rude phrase on a free site, please check your English translator. "Please help" is better.

Comment: I am sorry about my language. But I meant it in a polite way. I need this to be done using Mod_Rewrite not with Mod_proxy.